# Doctrine connection with db

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am about to start a project in doctrine symfony, but I have to make connection with multiple databases. One of them is an existing database (SQL SERVER) that cannot be mapped with ORM. Is there any possibility to connect with this db with another db that is NOT mapped in doctrine and work with controllers normally?

Comment: You can make multiple DB connections, just configure it. But what do you mean with "connect with this db with another db that is mapped in doctrine"?

Comment: you could configure only the DBAL layer and use it via connection. I suggest you to try to mapping the entity into a bundle, let me know if you need some info in this direction.

Comment: @Jean NOT MAPPED, edited question. I have a db that is indepedent and I dont want it to convert into ORM because it has a lot of procedures. How to connect with it?

Comment: @Matteo HOW can i do this for a database with a lot of procedures in it?

Comment: IF you have specific stored procedures that you need to call you need to pass trhow the connection (DBAL)

Comment: @Matteo can you suggest me any tutorial or  docs?

Comment: I share my experience, hope this help, let me know if you need more info and what kind of support you need.

Comment: hi @LauretaXhaferraj is this what you need? consider to upvote if this is useful for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I develop a multi-database sf2 app with doctrine2 orm mapping.

We use [intellectsoft-uk/MssqlBundle](https://github.com/intellectsoft-uk/MssqlBundle)

Our configuration is:

config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: acme_mysql
        connections:
            acme_mysql:
                host: %acme_mysql_database_host%
                port: %acme_mysql_database_port%
                dbname: %acme_mysql_database_name%
                user: %acme_mysql_database_user%
                password: %acme_mysql_database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
            acme_slqsrv:
                driver:         sqlsrv
                driver_class:   \Realestate\MssqlBundle\Driver\PDODblib\Driver
                host: %acme_slqsrv%
                port: %acme_slqsrv%
                dbname: %acme_slqsrv%
                user: %acme_slqsrv%
                password: %acme_slqsrv%
                charset:  UTF8
orm: #optional if you want to map some entity in doctrine2
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager: acme_mysql
    entity_managers:
        em_mysql:
            connection: acme_mysql
            mappings:
                AcmeMysqlBundle: ~
        em_sqlsrv:
            connection: acme_sqlsrv
            mappings:
                AcmeSqlSrvBundle: ~
```

This configuration permit you to take a connection instance in a controller/service and use it for access database and execute stored procedures and so on...

Hope this help